# How do you initialize mnesia on production?

Tags: erlang, mnesia, rebar3

I'm using rebar3 to produce a release, but how do I initialize mnesia on production?

If I write an "install" escript that does the `mnesia:create_schema([node()])` - it will use a completely different node name from the one that release uses.

So I end up creating a schema for "nonode@nonode" while production mnesia when I start my app with `my-app-1.0.0 start` tries to access "myapp@localhost" node.

Also, it is kind of a chicken-and-egg problem:

1. I can't start up my app without mnesia tables
2. I can't install my mnesia tables without my app running (as the same `node()` name as the app will use).

Just wandering if there is a good way to handle this?

Here is my install escript that I run independently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%% -*- erlang -*-
%%! -smp enable ls-mnesia debug verbose
-include("../include/rr.hrl").

main(_) ->
    application:set_env(mnesia, dir, "/usr/local/src/db/mnesia"),
    application:stop(mnesia),
    install([node()|nodes()]).

install(Nodes) ->
    case mnesia:create_schema(Nodes) of
        ok -> 
            rpc:multicall(Nodes, application, start, [mnesia]),
            read_store_create_tables(Nodes),
            event_store_create_tables(Nodes),
            rpc:multicall(Nodes, application, stop, [mnesia]);
        Err -> 
            error_logger:warning_msg("Could not create schema: ~p~n", [Err]),
            Err
    end.    

event_store_create_tables(Nodes) ->
    {_, ok} = mnesia:create_table(rr_events,
            [{attributes, record_info(fields, rr_events)},
             {disc_copies, Nodes},
             {type, bag}]).

read_store_create_tables(Nodes) ->
    % Initialize the actual data-tables for the projections
    {_, ok} = mnesia:create_table(rr_competencies,
            [{attributes, record_info(fields, rr_competencies)},
             {disc_copies, Nodes}]).
```

P.S.: I am using `rebar3` which uses `relx` to build releases.

Answer (score 1):

I am using my own [build system](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl) which was written mainly because of that exact requirement - ability to install and initialize a node before starting it. The idea is quite simple: there are [two releases](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/etc/reltool.config), in this particular example called `cmd` and `humbundee`. The `cmd` release doesn't start the main applications, only loads them. Then a special function is executed to initialize the node. The function is configured in the [`reltool.config`](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/etc/reltool.config) file. In this case it's [`hbd_setup`](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/lib/deploy/src/hbd_setup.erl) from the `deploy` application. That function reads the configuration file and either creates and initializes the mnesia database from a backup or creates a new database if the backup doesn't exist. Once the node is installed it's started using the proper release. The same steps are executed in development (directly from the source code) and in production (from an OTP release).

With that setup the problem you described doesn't exist because both releases are started from the same location, using almost the same command and configuration files (`builderl` generates them from the configuration in `reltool.config`).

---

You could employ the same idea with any build tool, including `rebar3` and `relx`, by executing these steps manually or with some sort of a script.

What `builderl` does is that it executes these steps automatically and provides an environment to execute them in the same way in development and production, e.g. see the [bottom of the `humbundee` project's README](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee#the-nitty-gritty---how-to-use-humbundee) file:

**Install the node.** This will start the `cmd` release and execute the `hbd_setup:install/2` function to initialize the node:

```
./bin/init.esh
```

**Start the node.** This will start the `humbundee` release, which starts all applications with their corresponding supervisor trees:

```
./bin/start.esh
```

---

`builderl` actually uses `rebar` to pull and compile [dependencies that depend on other projects](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/rebar.config), however it uses only OTP to create the release. It can also download dependencies itself using a [project-wide dependency file](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/deps-versions/master), which are then [compiled with `make`](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl/tree/master/makefiles) (compiling without the `make` is [work in progress](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl/commit/6d15d5a2ed669425af634629070a546c1b27eab4)). I hope that helps.

Comment: But how do you deal with making this all automated via build scripts (i.e. ansible)? The problem there is that an app, when started, is not like a script, and it runs as a service - so the script doesn't know when the app is _done_ initializing the database. (Wow, this is way more complicated than I imagined.)

Comment: Please check this answer (search for `init:stop()`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359040/idiomatic-way-to-ship-command-line-tools-written-in-erlang/36362156#36362156 Then this function: https://github.com/yoonka/builderl/blob/master/src/bld_init.erl#L902 Basically, there are two Erlang instances. When executing `./bin/init.esh` `builderl` runs in its own VM. It then starts the installed VM using the `cmd` release, configures it, and then shuts it down. If something goes wrong it returns code `1`. When `builderl` finishes its return code can be inspected by `make` or other script.